# Regex to allow specific and special characters

Tags: java, regex

I need to create a regex in java that allows the following:

Characters a-z, A-Z and àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸ
Numbers 0-9
Special characters: @ - /
Spaces between words

Currently I have this: '^[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF]+$'
which allows: a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸ - but does not allow spaces or the characters @ - /
I cannot figure out a regex that includes all of this, please help

I tried the following other regex variations:

```
'^\[a-zA-Z0-9!/-\\u00C0-\\u024F\\u1E00-\\u1EFF\]+$'
'^\[a-zA-Z0-9\\w+\\u00C0-\\u024F\\u1E00-\\u1EFF\]+$'
'^\[a-zA-Z0-9\\w+@/-\\u00C0-\\u024F\\u1E00-\\u1EFF\]+$'
```

Comment: Why did you escape character class `[` and `]` chars?

Answer (score 2):

```
^[-@/ a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF]+$'
```

A `-` is best added first in a character class to ensure it is not interpreted as range. For the other missing characters simply add them.

Also note that your ranges `\u00C0-\u024F` and `\u1E00-\u1EFF` add a lot more than just àèìòùÀÈÌÒÙáéíóúýÁÉÍÓÚÝâêîôûÂÊÎÔÛãñõÃÑÕäëïöüÿÄËÏÖÜŸ (and ranges can be a bit unreliable with different locals; might be best to explicit add all wanted characters)

And to match "between words" you probably want `\b[...]\b` instead of `^[...]$` which matches the entire input.

Answer (score -2):

This worked:

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9\u00C0-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF\@\/\-\s]+$'
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is @Paul Pazderski's answer. Please upvote when you have enough reputation to do so, rather than reposting as new answer.

Comment: @kenny_k looks like they both answered at the same time. user22293349 was a bit sooner in particular. It doesn't have any explanation though.

Comment: @S.B fair enough, didn't notice the timestamps. I didn't downvote, but it was flagged as low-quality - not sure how that voting went in the end.